# Can I make a chatroom for a network?

Tags: html, ajax, chat, chatroom

As an example if I have a small group of people at a college and I want to create a chat room application which each user can download and then open to view list of all available users to talk to and click one of the users in a list then a window pops and any text you enter goes to that specific person. How can I make this? I have made a chatroom using AJAX and html etc but I have never done a chatroom for a network such as the one you have in schools or work places. What language would I need? All help is appreciated since I am total new to this.

I read something on internet about winsock connections but there wasn't much I could find.

Comment: You can still use HTML and AJAX with an internal server.

Comment: VBA is a wrong option for this. I created one such program many many years ago using VB6 and winsock. You can now using any DOT Net language to create a chat application.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I can do this with AJAX?

Comment: @Nadal: The same way you do anything else with AJAX, but with a server behind your firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sockets for network programming in java.

Look at this Deitel's tutorial about a java messenger application.

http://www.deitel.com/books/jhtp7/DeitelMessenger.pdf